# How can i send an extra parameter with my link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My view contains this link to redirect to the index page for people.

```
 <%= link_to 'No', '/people' %>
```

I want to send an extra flag to the index method of the people controller so it will do something extra in case this link is clicked. I've tried a ton of different things, none of which work. I tried using the more complicated syntax with :controller => :people_controller, :action => :index...but since i'm coming from the show view it sends the ID and messes up my routes.

**How can i send an extra parameter with this link_to?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'No', people_path(extra_parameter: "Veg") %>
```